# Editing structure instance's member values inside single/multiple thread(s)

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, struct, shared-memory

I am attempting to edit a structure's member value(s) within single/multiple threads on Windows, consider the following example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int val;
} object;

DWORD WINAPI edit_obj(LPVOID *lpParameter) {
    object a = *(object*)lpParameter;
    a.val = 20;

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    object a;
    a.val = 5;
    printf("a.val before edit: %d\n", a.val);

    CreateThread(0, 0, edit_obj, &a, 0, 0);
    printf("a.val after edit: %d\n", a.val);

}
```

I am aware I am creating a replicated object of `a`. I am clueless to how this can be achieved or if possible, this example I've provided is how far I've come. Is dereferencing the `lpParameter` pointer necessary? Or is there a way in which I can edit the structure that is thread-safe?

Example/undesired code's output:

```
a.val before edit: 5
a.val after edit: 5
```

Expected/desired output (The output I am attempting to achieve):

```
a.val before edit: 5
a.val after edit: 20
```

My overall question is how can I point to the `object` structure instance `a` so that I can edit the member(s) value(s) of `a` within the `edit_obj` thread?

Comment: object * a=lpParameter;  a->val=20;  That may work correctly eitber because the main thread could print the field before the thread 'edits' it.

Comment: @MartinJames I just tested your suggestion to no avail, a.val is not equal to 20 after making your provided changes.

Comment: Fix tbe race by waiting on tbe thread handle or using an event/semaphore.  Andreas explains in more detail below.  Waiting for the thread completion is just one API call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The function `edit_obj` does not modify the object `a` of the function `main`, but rather a copy of it.
2. Even if #1 were fixed, you would still have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). After you call `CreateThread`, you do not wait for the thread to finish its work. Therefore, depending on whether it has finished or not, the following `printf` line may printf a modified or an unmodified value of the object. To fix this, you must call `WaitForSingleObject` on the thread.

To fix #1, you can write the following:

```
DWORD WINAPI edit_obj(LPVOID *lpParameter) {
   ((object*)lpParameter)->val = 20;

    return 0;
}
```

To fix #2, you can write the following:

```
int main() {
    [...]

    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, edit_obj, &a, 0, 0);
    WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );
    CloseHandle( hThread );
    printf("a.val after edit: %d\n", a.val);

}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example in the form of c code that works?

Comment: Calling WFSO() on the thread handle is one way.  There are otber signaling mechanisms available.

Comment: @dkkl_codex: I have now edited my answer and provided the code to fix both issues.

Comment: Ok thank you! Is `((object*)lpParameter)->val = 20;` a typecast?

Comment: Yes. `lpParameter` has the data type `void *` and I am casting it to the data type `object *`, before dereferencing it with the `->` operator. The additional parentheses are necessary, because `->` has higher [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the type cast operator.

Comment: @MartinJames: Yes, you are right. If the worker thread were doing more work afterwards, then it would probably be appropriate to signal the main thread with a [condition variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)) as soon as it is allowed to read the modified object. However, conditon variables have a different meaning in the Win32 API. I believe using [Win32 Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-functions#event-functions) would be most appropriate in this case.